# Developing an indexing scheme for list of all non-decreasing sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, math

Suppose that we are considering a sorted list of all non-decreasing sequences with values in the range `(1, max_num)` and `num_slots` elements in each sequence, how can I find the index of some given member sequence in `O(1)` time complexity? I **am not** actually given the entire list up-front, I just want to find the index of some member sequence were the list of all sequences to exist.

For a concrete example, suppose that `max_num = 3` and `num_slots = 4`. Then there are 15 sequences (or generally, there are `(max_num + num_slots - 1) choose (num_slots)` sequences):

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 3],
 [1, 1, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 1, 3, 3],
 [1, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 3],
 [1, 3, 3, 3],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 3],
 [2, 2, 3, 3],
 [2, 3, 3, 3],
 [3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

So given inputs of a sequence like `[1, 2, 2, 3]` along with the information `max_num = 3`, I am trying to write a function that would return its correct index of 7. I do not actually have the list of all sequences to work with.

---

**Background info**

I have come up with an algorithm to generate all non-decreasing sequences I care about, but this doesn't seem completely relevant for generating the index of a particular member sequence without the whole list of sequences materialized.

```
def gen(max_num, num_slots, l = None): 
    if l is None: 
        l = [[1] * num_slots] 
    cur = l[-1].copy() 
    for i in reversed(range(num_slots)): 
        if cur[i] < max_num: 
            cur[i] += 1 
            for j in range(i+1, num_slots): 
                cur[j] = cur[i] 
            l.append(cur) 
            return gen(max_num, num_slots, l) 
    return l
```

Comment: You can just do seq_index = sequences.index(sequence)

Comment: @postoronnim Sorry, I should have specified I am wanting a `O(1)` solution.

Comment: You don't need to generate the series, this is an pure math question that can most likely treated with recursion: If you look at all of the 4-list that start with 2 or larger in your generated lists, you'll find they are the same with all element with 4-list, max-num=2 (when you minus all numbers by 1)

Comment: @RockyLi I apologize but I don't entirely follow. I agree the series generation isn't necessary, I just mentioned it because it seemed somewhat relevant.

Comment: "Given a sorted list of..." - are you *actually given* that list, or are you just supposed to find the index a particular element would have if that list were constructed? Such a list is a giant waste of memory in almost any circumstance. Even if you want to iterate through all such sequences (usually a bad idea), there's no reason to materialize a list up front.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah no sorry I worded the question terribly, let me fix it - I don't have the list materialized up front, and it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll elaborate on @DavidFrank's answer on why it is O(length+max_num) and give a more easily understand example (a bit more complex too).

To start with, observe:

Assume the total series possibility in *F(length, max_num)* = X

Then for all of possibilities in X that starts with 1, e.g. [1, ....], we have a count of *F(length-1, max_num)* within this group.

For all the possibility in X that does not start with 1, e.g. [2, ....] or [3, ....], we have a count of *F(length,      max_num-1)*.

Thus we can use recursion to get this in O(length*max_num) (can become O(length+max_num) if we use memoization) number of complexity:

```
# This calculate the total number of X of possible entry given (length, max_num)
def calc_sum(length, max_num):
    if max_num == 1:
        return 1
    elif length == 1:
        return max_num
    else:
        total = calc_sum(length-1, max_num) + calc_sum(length, max_num-1)
        return total
```

Now we examine the result to see if we can make it O(1):

```
# This is clearly not going to make it O(1), so now we need some generalizations to NOT run this recursion.
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((6,6))
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        arr[i, j] = calc_sum(i+1, j+1)
print(arr)
```

The result is:

```
[[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.]
 [  1.   3.   6.  10.  15.  21.]
 [  1.   4.  10.  20.  35.  56.]
 [  1.   5.  15.  35.  70. 126.]
 [  1.   6.  21.  56. 126. 252.]
 [  1.   7.  28.  84. 210. 462.]]
```

This is a pascal's triangle, if you look diagonally to the top right. The diagonals of pascal's triangle are defined   by (x choose y)

This makes it clear that it cannot be O(1), and will at least be O(length+max_num) because this is the general complexity of (Choose) function.

We've went all the way to prove that an O(1) solution is impossible, unless we constrain (length + max_num) to be constant.

```
# We can expand by solving it now:
from scipy.special import comb # this is choose function.

def get_index(my_list, max_num):
    my_list = np.array(my_list)
    if len(my_list) == 1:
        return my_list[0] - 1
    elif my_list[0] == 1:
        return get_index(my_list[1:], max_num)
    elif my_list[0] != 1:
        return get_index(my_list - 1, max_num - 1) + comb(len(my_list)-2+max_num, max_num-1)

get_index([1,2,2,3],3) # 7
```

The aggregated complexity of the final function with the `comb()` is still O(length + max_num) as the complexity of everything outside `comb` is O(length + max_num) as well.

Answer (score 4):

This one is `O(|seq| + max_num)`. Note that this is still much faster than the naive generate all and search approach, which is exponential in `|seq|`.

The idea is that you count the sequences before the input sequence. For example,
you want to know what's the index of [2, 4, 5, 6] when max_num = 6.

- Count [1, *, *, *]
- Count [2, 2, *, *]
- Count [2, 3, *, *]
- (Note: you cannot count [2, 4, *, *], because then you would include [2, 4, 6, 6] which comes after your input. You should always go until one less than your input at the given index)
- Count [2, 4, 4, *]
- Count [2, 4, 5, 5]

(for each row, you can use your formula, `(max_num + num_slots - 1) choose (num_slots)` and sum them up)

```
def combinations(slots, available):
    return choose(slots + available - 1, slots)

def find_index(seq, max_num):
    res = 0
    for digit_index in xrange(len(seq)):
        prev = seq[digit_index - 1] if digit_index > 0 else 1
        for digit in xrange(prev, seq[digit_index]):
            res += combinations(len(seq) - digit_index - 1, max_num - digit + 1)
    return res


print find_index([1, 2, 2, 3], 3)
```

Comment: This is a clever solution but I don't think your `O` is correct. You can't compute `choose` in `O(1)`.  I suspect it should be something like `O(max_num*(|seq|+max_num))`. Consider finding the position of something like `[1, 1000, 2000]` and of `[1,2,3, ..., 1000]`. On the other hand `O(1)` requested by OP is clearly impossible because it takes `O(|seq|)` just to read the whole `seq`.

Answer (score 1):

There is bijection from the k-subsets of `{1...n}` (with repetition) to k-subsets of `{1...n + k − 1}` (without repetition) by mapping `{c_0, c_1...c_(k−1)}` to `{c_0, c_(1+1), c_(2+2)...c_(k−1+k−1)}` (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144408/indexing-combinations-with-repetition)).

Once converted, just use your favourite combination ranking utility.

```
[3, 3, 3, 3]  -->  [3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 3, 3]  -->  [2, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 2, 3, 3]  -->  [2, 3, 5, 6]
[2, 2, 2, 3]  -->  [2, 3, 4, 6]
[2, 2, 2, 2]  -->  [2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 3, 3]  -->  [1, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 3]  -->  [1, 3, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 2, 3]  -->  [1, 3, 4, 6]
[1, 2, 2, 2]  -->  [1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 1, 3, 3]  -->  [1, 2, 5, 6]
[1, 1, 2, 3]  -->  [1, 2, 4, 6]
[1, 1, 2, 2]  -->  [1, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 3]  -->  [1, 2, 3, 6]
[1, 1, 1, 2]  -->  [1, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 1]  -->  [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

```py
import pyncomb

def convert(m, S):
  return (m + len(S) - 1, [ x-1 + i for x,i in zip(S, list(xrange(len(S)))) ])

def rank(m, S):
  k, s = convert(m, S)
  return pyncomb.ksubsetcolex.rank(k, s)

print rank(3, [1,2,2,3])
# 7
```

Answer (score 0):

For each digit, find the difference between that and the lowest digit.  Add 1 for each changed position to the right of any altered digit

```
idx = 0;
for i in range(0,num_slots):
    d = SEQ[i]
    idx += d-min_num
    if (d > min_num):
        idx += num_slots-1 - i
```

For example:
 `[1,1,1,3]` is `0 + 0 + 0 + (2+0)` or `2`
`[1,2,3,3]` is `0 + (1+2) + (2+1) + (2+0)` or `8`
`[3,3,3,3]` is `(2+3) + (2+2) + (2+1) + (2+0)` or `14`

Comment: This is O(num_slots).

Comment: This looks promising! It seems to work for the case with 4 slots and 3 as the max number. However, it doesn't appear to work for many other cases, for instance with 2 as a max number instead of 3 (unless I am not coding it up properly).

Comment: Are there any constraints  relating max_num and num_slots?   With max 2/ slots 4 It works if you don't add the positional bonus.  With a larger max, it gets non-linear on position.